# Include a maven task inside a maven

Tags: maven, jar

I need to create a war of my project using maven and while creating the war I need to include some source which is in another repository. Also the sources which is in another repo need to be added as jar in my war under WEB-INF\lib. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: why would you want to do it?  I believe what you are going to do is simply against Maven's philosophy, and in most case not rational.  Can you tell us why you think you want to do that?  And, what's the "repo" you are referring in your question? Maven repo? or SVN Repo?

Comment: "repo" is referring Git here. This is my scenario: I have a java project which contains the dependent sources of the web project(war). So I need the java project to be created as a jar and added under the WEB-INF\lib dir.

Comment: I don't believe you need the source of a project in most case.  In case of WAR, please see the built-in WAR overlay behavior fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

The other sources inside the alternative repository are Maven project?

If so, you can just compile it and add with dependencies mechanism..

Comment: Is there any way to include that compilation mechanism inside my war creation without doing two independent process?

Comment: Yes....Sure! I'm thinking about a Maven plugin (you have to develop)..this one can simply connect to the repository, download the souruce, compile that and add to the war lib...But you will have to develop it, and if you never develop a Maven plugin, it possibly will costs too much time for you... But for me the simpliest solution is just convert the project inside the alternative repository to Maven project...Is it feasible?